# Using Use prepared statements and parameterized queries in PHP and MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

I am learning how to use prepared statements in my simple login system to make it more secure.

I have followed a few different tutorials to get it working but cant get it to work. When i enter the username and password wrong it gives me the error. When i enter the username and password correct i still get the error.

What am i doing wrong?

I am new to this so apologies for any obvious errors.

I have also looked into hashing my password as it is being stored as plain text in the database at the moment but that will be my next step after i get this working.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message

if($SERVER['REQUESTMETHOD'] == 'POST') {
if (empty($POST['username']) || empty($POST['password'])) {

$error = "Enter Username and Password";

}

else
{
// Define $username and $password
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//connect to database
include('dbconx.php');

}

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * from admin where password=? AND username=?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password); 
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $username, $password);
$stmt->store_result();
if($stmt->num_rows == 1) //To check if the row exists
{

        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username; // Initializing Session
        header("location: confirm.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page

    }
else {
$error = "Username or Password is incorrect";
}

mysqli_close($con); // Closing Connection
}

?>
```

Comment: What is the "error"?

Comment: Never use `SELECT *` with `bind_result()`. You need to explicitly set the order, ie `SELECT id, username, password`. That being said, there's no need to `SELECT` the password or username

Comment: Oh, you have your arguments backwards. Your query binds `password` then `username` but your `bind_param()` uses `$username` then `$password`

Comment: The error is just stating that username or password is wrong....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your bound parameter arguments backwards. Your query binds `password` then `username` but your `bind_param()` uses `$username` then `$password`.

---

I've never been a fan of using the number of rows returned to determine existence. Instead, you can simply use `fetch()`. It will return a boolean value indicating whether or not there was a result.

For example

```php
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id from admin where password = ? AND username = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $password, $username); // note the order
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id);
if ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['login_user_id'] = $id; // probably important
    header("Location: confirm.php");
    exit; // always exit after a "Location" header
} else {
    $error = "Username or Password is incorrect";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice Phil.  I have changed my code a little and still having the same problem.  No matter what i enter into username and password fields the error still appears and does not redirect me to my confirm page. Any suggestions?

Comment: I managed to fix it by changing to code a bit to this: $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = ? AND password = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password); 
$stmt->execute();  
$stmt->bind_result($id, $username, $password);

Answer (score -1):

`mysqli_stmt::store_result` should be called before `mysqli_stmt::bind_result`, also you would need to call `mysqli_stmt::seek_data` and `mysqli_stmt::fetch` to get the result.

Example :

```
<?php

$db = new Mysqli(...);

$inputUsername = $_POST['username'] ?? '';
$inputPassword = $_POST['password'] ?? '';

$statment = $db->prepare('SELECT `id`,`username`,`password` FROM `admin` WHERE `username` = ?');

$statment->bind_param('s',$inputUsername);

$statment->execute();

$statment->store_result();

$statment->bind_result($id,$username,$password);

if($statment->num_rows) {

    $statment->data_seek(0);
    $statment->fetch();

    /**
    * this is not secure
    * @see http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
    */
    if($inputPassword === $password) {
        echo sprintf('Welcome, %s!',$username);
    } else {
        echo 'Incorrect password!';
    }

} else {

    echo sprintf('No such user with the given username (%s)',$inputUsername);

}

$statment->close();
$db->close();
```

Answer (score -1):

Removed `bind_result` and `store_result` for `get_result` and `fetch_assoc`. It makes getting db records more flexible and stable.

Also added `exit();` after redirection so no other codes will be executed after redirect command.

Typo in:

`if (empty($POST['username']) || empty($POST['password']))`

- ^ `$POST` should be `$_POST` instead.

`$error` is not being checked properly if empty or not. And still goes through `mysqli functions` block even if there is an error. Fixed that by creating an appropriate `if statement` that encloses the `mysqli funtions` block.

Also added proper indentation to the code for readability.

**New Code:**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message

$_POST['username'] = isset( $_POST['username'] ) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
$_POST['password'] = isset( $_POST['password'] ) ? $_POST['password'] : '';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $error = "Enter Username and Password";
    }
    else{
        // Define $username and $password
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        //connect to database
        include('dbconx.php');
    }

    if( $error == "" ) {
        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * from students where username=? AND password=?");
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        if($result->num_rows == 1) {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $row['username']; // Initializing Session
            header("location: confirm.php");exit(); // Redirecting To Other Page
        }
        else {
            $error = "Username or Password is incorrect";
        }

        mysqli_close($con); // Closing Connection
    }
    echo $error;
}

?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Answers should have explanations.

Comment: Added explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Karlo. I have changed my code a little and still having the same problem. No matter what i enter into username and password fields the error still appears and does not redirect me to my confirm page. Any suggestions?

Comment: Updated Code...